# C++ development for Linux on Windows

Tags: c++, ide

I am trying to setup a development environment for Linux C++ application. Because I'm limited to my laptop (vista) which provides essential office applications, I want to program and access email, word at the same time.
I'd prefer a local Windows IDE. SSH to a company linux server and using VI doesn't seem productive to me. Even using some IDE installed on the linux server doesn't seem good to me, because I can't do the work at home.
So does Eclipse CDT + MinGW work for me, or is there any other choice?

Thanks.

ZXH

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not install a Linux virtual machine on your laptop, in VMware or similar?  That way you can test while you're developing too.

Comment: VirtualBox is free, VMware costs money.

Comment: VMware Server is free, and does the job.

Comment: virtualbox with an ubuntu server is what I use. I love it. I use putty so that I can resize it, and emacs for editing. Oneiric so that I get the gcc 4.6.0 version.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try http://cygwin.com/

Answer (score 5):

Is it a GUI app? And do you have to target Linux specifically? If not, Qt (http://trolltech.com/) may be something that you can use. It would allow you to more or less develop your whole application on Windows, and then spend a few hours on a linux machine getting the whole thing ported...

Answer (score 2):

Qt is the best choice. I develop with tis tool for a long time. And you can develop with the same ide : QtCreator and the same framework : Qt on MacOS, Linux based or Windows plateform...
Moreover, specifically on Linux, Qt is well integrated with Kdevelop !

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio, which I feel is an excellent IDE, you can try to set it up to use GCC/G++.  I've done this before, back in the Visual Studio 6 days.  As long as you aren't using any Windows-specific libraries and write portable C++, you can compile and test on Windows, then periodically ensure that the code also compiles properly for Linux.

Another approach, one that I actually prefer, is to host your source and make files on the Linux box, share the files through Samba, then use your Windows IDE/text editor to edit those files.  Then, you can do the compiling through an SSH terminal.  Sure, you'd lose the convenience of being able to compile through your IDE, but at least you wouldn't have to muck around getting the compiler set up on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linux server available to you, you could also use NX to log in graphically, and use a Linux IDE there like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), or *shudder* Eclipse. Of course, there's nothing unproductive about shelling in and using VIM. I find it's a good way to shake out the IDE-induced cobwebs every now and again. Happy coding however you end up doing so!

Answer (score 0):

I use (and recommend) [Netbeans for C/C++ Development](http://www.netbeans.org/features/cpp/) together with Cygwin to develop POSIX applications on Windows that will run on Linux/Solaris later on.

It is pretty easy to setup as long as you stick to the stable version of Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar position 2-3 years ago and tried several approaches, but the only one that really worked wor me was vim+ssh (+gdb, make, svn, etc). But again, I use vim even for Windows development.

Answer (score 0):

[This slideshow (PDF)](http://www.appinf.com/download/EclipseEmbeddedLinuxSlides.pdf) walks through how to set up a cross compiler from Windows to Linux.